# java regex insert character as specific index position

Tags: java, regex

I need to simply insert character "/" in the 3rd position of string.

ie `"EURUSD"` becomes `"EUR/USD"`.

I'm using some program GUI to do this, it accepts a Regex Pattern and a Replacement.

I know this must be super simple but I can't seem to find a simple answer.

Comment: Can you replace `^(.{3})` with `\1/`?

Comment: that gives me  "1/USD"

Comment: Sorry, `$1/`, rather?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `^.{3}` (3 [`{3}`] characters [`.`] at the start of the string [`^`]) with `$&/` (the match `$&`, followed by a `/`).

Answer (score 1):

Use a look behind:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=^...)", "/");
```

Using a look behind, which doesn't consume any input, means the replacement term is simply your new character (no need for back references).